# Equivalent of OracleParameter [C#/.NET/SQL Server]

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, oracle, ado.net

I working on a database migration (from Oracle to SQL Server) and in this context, I need to change the DAL layer of an ASP.NET project. Part of this is finding the SQL Server equivalent of the class OracleParameter (From Oracle.DataAccess.dll).

So I would like to know which class I have to use, is it DbParameter or another one?

Comment: What does OracleParameter inherit from or implement? `DbParameter`? Then wouldn't it make sense there's an equivalent class in the SQL Server libraries that also inherits from that, and probably has "parameter" in the name? And where does one look for information about the libraries that come with .NET? The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient(v=vs.110).aspx)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best to use:

SqlParameter

Eg:

```
var parameter = new SqlParameter();
            parameter.ParameterName = "@paramName";
            parameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            parameter.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int;
            //parameter.IsNullable = true;
            parameter.Value = DaysInStock;
```